# Partial inheriting of xml-comments with included <inheritdoc/>

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, inheritance, comments

I just found out that  is now included by default in visual studio. So I started writing comments for my class which makes extensive use of inheritance. What I am trying to do is inherit only parts of my decription from above. So for example when writting xml-comments for the  constructor of an inherited class, I want him to inherit the description for my parameters but want to specify an more specific comment for the summary field. I tried this approch but unfortunally it doesn't worked:

```
    ''' <summary>
''' Creates a new belt-instance
''' </summary>
''' <param name="OpcClient"><inheritdoc/></param>
''' <param name="BaseNode"><inheritdoc/></param>
''' <param name="PropertyChangedNotificationsRequested"><inheritdoc/>/param>
Sub New(ByRef OpcClient As OpcUaClient, ByVal BaseNode As OpcNodeId, ByVal PropertyChangedNotificationsRequested As Boolean)
    MyBase.New(OpcClient, BaseNode, PropertyChangedNotificationsRequested)
    ...
End Sub
```

Always inheriting the the whole comment seemt to be a bit overdone, because the more you go uo the inheritance-chain, the mor general and unspecific the comments get most of the time. **How to achieve that kind of partial inheritance of comments?**

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a solution in internet, but tried a bit with different solutions. The following one seems to work

1. Add all things you want to override.
2. Add the   afterwards.

Example:

```
    ''' <summary>
''' I am overriding
''' </summary>
''' <param name="BaseNode">I am also</param>
''' <inheritdoc/>
Sub New(ByRef OpcClient As OpcUaClient, ByVal BaseNode As OpcNodeId, ByVal PropertyChangedNotificationsRequested As Boolean)
    MyBase.New(OpcClient, BaseNode, PropertyChangedNotificationsRequested)
    ...
End Sub
```

If there is also a more clean solution or some additional information regarding this case I would like to hear about it.